# How to set a outlet to a button with a action connected to it?

Tags: iphone, c++, xcode

I have a button in my app, and currently I have a IBAction connected to it through interface builder, but I need to connect a outlet so I can declare it in my code like `button.hidden = yes` but I can't do that because the button only has an IBAction, how would I set the outlet and the action to the button? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Hold Control and drag the button to the interface() section. Or declare the outlet first, the right click on the button, you can see a menu that can choose these properties.

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner and I don't know how to do that, could you explain in more detail? thanks

Comment: You are using storyboard or interface builder? Whatever you use, you go to where you create the button, then right click on the button you created, there should be a menu popup, you can choose IBOutlet and IBAction here. But you need declare them in your code file first.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is

```
button.hidden = yes
```

and my code is `button.hidden = YES;`

I hope this solves your problem.